# How do I load taxonomy terms?

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

I want to load taxonomy terms by tid, but I didn't found how. Only how to load taxonomy by name, but now I have term id and I need to get value of fields.

I call this on public function `build()` for custom block.

My code:

```
$terms = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadTree('menu');
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    //var_dump($term->tid);
}
```

Comment: Check [taxonomy_term_load_multiple](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_load_multiple/8.2.x)

Comment: Thx i use $entityManager->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadMultiple($terms);. But now all field (preperties) are private :'(

Comment: Yes, but you can get their values with the term methods, for example $name = $term->getName(); Look into the TermInterface to see which methods are available.

Comment: The linked answer is very good - `\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadTree($vid, $parent, $max_depth, $load_entities);` - the fourth function parameter allows to get back the actual term objects, not just the tids.

Answer (score 20):

in Single Manner

```
    $term = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->load(TID);
    $value = $term->FIELD_MACHINENAME->value;
```

Example : load title and language of term id =2

```
    $term = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->load(2);
    $title = $term->name->value;
    langcode = $term->langcode->value;
```

And for load Multiple as you wanted

```
  $terms = $entityManager->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadMultiple($t‌​erms);
  foreach ($terms as $term) {
      var_dump($term->tid->value); //return tid of term
   var_dump($term->name->value); //return title of term
  }
```

Comment: loadMultiple($t‌​erms)... what is $terms

Comment: @AlxVallejo An array of taxonomy term IDs.

Answer (score 9):

You can also do like this:

```
$tids = [1,2,3];
$terms = \Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term::loadMultiple($tids);
```

Example from :
http://www.drupal8.ovh/en/tutoriels/17/get-taxonomy-terms-of-a-vocabulary-drupal-8